# Sort method not working properly

Tags: java

I am trying to sort nodes in a BST by a specific value, and for some reason it is just not working properly and I have no idea what I'm missing...

Based on user input, the menu will display a record either above or below a certain value (GPA in this case). I know, not the best way to have it, but it's not finished yet:

```
    public void sortGPA (double min, double max) {
        inOrderTraverseTree(root, min, max);
    }
```

Which calls

```
public void inOrderTraverseTree(Node focusNode, double min, double max) {

    if (focusNode != null) {
        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild, min, max);

        if (root.gpa >= min && root.gpa <= max){                
            System.out.println(focusNode);
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("");
        }

        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild, min, max);
    }// end if
}// end inOrderTraverseTree
```

So every time I run this, if the input is `(minVal, 4.0)` then absolutely nothing is displayed. If it is `(0.0, max)` then it displays the whole list, even those values that are outside the given range. There is either something super small that I'm missing, or huge that I'm missing ha so I would appreciate any feed back if there is anything you see.

Here is an example of the outputs:

```
All students: 
19    Kyle Johnson Chemistry     1.43
24    Chloe Young History     2.23
23    Bill Guy Accounting     3.32
25    Ashley Holmes Accounting     3.75
22    John Smith History     4.00
---------------------------------
Here are the students above a 3.5 GPA: 
19    Kyle Johnson Chemistry     1.43
24    Chloe Young History     2.23
23    Bill Guy Accounting     3.32
25    Ashley Holmes Accounting     3.75
22    John Smith History     4.00
---------------------------------
Here are the students below a 3.0 GPA: 
---------------------------------
```

Comment: Should you be comparing the root.gpa or the focusNode.gpa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is you're performing a call on root.gpa, no matter where the node in the tree you're referencing is. Try this.

```
public void inOrderTraverseTree(Node focusNode, double min, double max) 
{

    if (focusNode != null) {
        inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild, min, max);

    if (focusNode.gpa >= min && focusNode.gpa <= max){                
        System.out.println(focusNode);
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("");
    }

    inOrderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild, min, max);
    }// end if
}// end inOrderTraverseTree
```

Comment: Yup! that was it haha I knew it had to be something stupid like that... thank you so much! it's one of those things where you spend forever trying to manipulate little bits to see what went wrong and you know there is something little your missing but you spent so long looking that you overlook it. Thanks!